# The view Index or master was not found azure deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am new to `Azure Deployment`. I have an `ASP.NET MVC`  app running fine locally working fine. Trying to deploy it on Azure. Using a `BitBucket` repository to create the app. But accessing it gives

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/User/Index.aspx
~/Views/User/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/User/Index.cshtml
~/Views/User/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I have used `Kudu Console` to check that the `D:\home\site\repository` has every bit of the project. But `D:\home\site\wwwroot` misses `controllers` etc.

I think that it access `wwwroot` directory as the project directory. But I am not sure about that.

Any pointers to actual issue and solution are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have used Kudu Console to check that the D:\home\site\repository has every bit of the project. But D:\home\site\wwwroot misses controllers etc.

As I known, for classical (regardless of .NET Core applications) ASP.NET MVC Website, the `Controllers` would compiled into the .DLL file with the name of your web application. You could find it under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin` via KUDU.

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Since your website could work locally, I assumed that there be something wrong with the web content you deployed to Azure. You could try to check the *.cshtml files have been deployed to Azure (under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views`) successfully via KUDU.

Also, please make sure the `Build Action` of your views has been configured as "Content" as follows:

[image]

Also, for deploying apps to Azure Web App, you could follow this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy).

Comment: Thanks @Bruce for your time. It's working now. Actually I had problem with my VS. Additionaly I followed `Build Action`configured to `Content` and this solves the problem.